# Use my home server dns for my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, cname-record, a-record

I purchased a domain name from a hosting website. I do not want to use their dns management (A records, CNAME etc). I want to configure DNS on my home server. How should I use my configured DNS on home server for my purchased domain?

Once this is achieved, can I configure mail accounts (@purchased-domain-name) on my home server where DNS is configured? I do not want to use their MX records either.

It is fine if server is turned off, no one is able to access my website or send me emails.

Domain is purchased means I have registered in BIND and their DNS management is making things easy for me to point my site to any server but I do not want to use hosting company services. I did not want to purchase domain from them either but I do not know how to register in BIND without purchasing a domain from hosting company.

Please comment.

***Update 1***

May be I could not ask properly and ended with two negative points and a closed thread. Trying again with different words.

I have purchased a domain abc.com from a hosting company. It is really easy to configure A records and CNAME for the domain. I have done it before for 2-3 domains.
I was just being curious suppose I do not configure A records for this new domain in hosting company's DNS management, can I configure DNS for this real domain on my home server?

I know it is a bad idea, server can be down sometimes or some other issues but just a curiosity, if I configure this real domain on my local home server but my question is still site can be opened if DNS has been configured on home server for real domain? If yes, How the domains find that its dns is configured on my home server?

I have found so many tutorials to configure home based dns server for fake domains to access them locally. I am not able to understand its advantage as we can easily access those domain locally after updating the hosts file. Why to follow this lengthy procedure, if we can not access them out side LAN?

I tried to find answers on various sites but I am not able to get it real domain dns configuration vs home server dns configuration and what is the significance of nameserver in this procedure? Why do we need to configure name server locally for home dns?

Does this make sense? Please comment.

Thank You

Comment: DNS needs to be always on, and it's a really basic service. There are few good reasons to run a DNS server yourself.

Comment: running DNS for the necessary *public* records like mail from a home server is an extremely terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

After purchasing a **Domain** from a hosting go in to the **DNS Manager** of that hosting and look for the option to change the **Name Servers** for that **Domain**.

With my hosting i was forced to supply at least 2 **Name Servers** on different public IPv4 IPs, I did this by using a VPS (Virtual Private Server) with an extra public IPv4 IP +(€1/Month).

p.s.

- Just like a regular **DNS Record** changing the **Name Servers** might take a while to propagate globally.
- Make sure that the DNS Server allows **DNS Query's** from the Internet by allowing the subnet: 0.0.0.0/0.
- Make sure that **DNS Recursion** is disabled on the DNS Server for external clients by only allowing these subnets: 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16.
- Make sure your DNS server is reachable by configuring things like port-forwarding and firewall rules.
- The use of a home (dynamic) IPv4 address, a single server, 2 servers in the same region is not recommended but for testing it works fine.